# Get all text boxes value with two conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple textboxes with same class and different different id's. I want to apply two search criteria in for each loop. For example, I have these text fields:-

```
<input type="text" id="grid_5_collect_businame" class="search_ ui-autocomplete-input" style="width:100%;" value="" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" id="grid_5_client_businame" class="search_" style="width:100%;" value="">
<input type="text" id="grid_5_collnurs" class="search_" style="width:100%;" value="">
<input type="text" id="grid_6_collect_businame" class="search_ ui-autocomplete-input" style="width:100%;" value="" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" id="grid_6_client_businame" class="search_" style="width:100%;" value="">
<input type="text" id="grid_6_collnurs" class="search_" style="width:100%;" value="">
```

Now i want to retrieve all those text boxes value which has class 'search_' and those id starts with 'grid_5', How i ca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combine multiple conditions like

```
$('input.search_[id^=grid_5]')
```

Comment: @BhojendraNepal OP said `I want to apply two search criteria in for each loop`... so indicating OP knows how to loop... so the problem might be only in how to do the filter

Comment: If first i get all the records then apply a filter then this process is too slow, I want to made it too fast, I want to search only  all those who satisfy these conditions.

Comment: @namneetsingh all the selectors used above are css3 supported... so a native filter will be applied in this case which is as fast as it can get....

Comment: @ArunPJohny Or like this? `$('input[class="search_"][id^="grid_5"]')`

Comment: @BhojendraNepal could be `text boxes value which has class 'search_'` is confusing...

Comment: @namneetsingh if you are so much worried about performance add a very specific class to all the target elements and use it as the only selector... see http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-comparison-001

Answer (score 0):

You need to checkthe IDs using regex `.match()` and filter out the qualifying IDs using `.filter()`.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var filteredTextboxes = $("input.search_").filter(function(element){
  var id = this.getAttribute('id');
  if(id.match(/^grid_5/))
    return id;
});

console.dir(filteredTextboxes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="grid_5_collect_businame" class="search_ ui-autocomplete-input" style="width:100%;" value="" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" id="grid_5_client_businame" class="search_" style="width:100%;" value="">
<input type="text" id="grid_5_collnurs" class="search_" style="width:100%;" value="">
<input type="text" id="grid_6_collect_businame" class="search_ ui-autocomplete-input" style="width:100%;" value="" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" id="grid_6_client_businame" class="search_" style="width:100%;" value="">
<input type="text" id="grid_6_collnurs" class="search_" style="width:100%;" value="">
```

Readup:

- [`.match()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
- [`.getAttribute()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute)